# How to add contents of one collection to a new collection

Tags: generics, collections, kotlin

I'm trying to override a method that calls the superclass and adds the returned values to a new collection (this is required because the superclass' return value is immutable).

The idiomatic Java for this is as follows:

```java
public class JaxrsApplication extends Application {

    @Override public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>(super.getClasses());
        classes.add(PlainTextWriter.class);
        classes.add(PageResource.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to implement an equivalent in Kotlin without success:

```kotlin
public class JaxrsApplication() : Application() {

    override fun getClasses(): MutableSet<Class<out Any?>>? {
        val classes = hashSetOf<Class<out Any?>>() 
        classes.addAll(super.getClasses())          // <= compiler error!
        classes.add(javaClass<PlainTextWriter>())
        classes.add(javaClass<PageResource>())
        return classes
    }

}
```

It seems to be a type inference problem on the addAll function but I'm not sure how to resolve it. Help appreciated :-)

---

For future readers, the reason I was confused here is due to the mismatch in types in the error popup:

[image: error pop-up]

`MutableSet` implements `Iterable`, the key here is the final '?' character  on the 'Found' line indicating the returned value is nullable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get compiler error because `super.getClasses` returns `nullable` type, but `addAll` accepts only `not-null` argument.

It's possible to fix this problem with `if-statement` or `!!` operator:

1.

```
val superClasses = super.getClasses()
if (superClasses != null) {
    classes.addAll(superClasses)
}
```

2.

```
classes.addAll(super.getClasses()!!)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin M9 you should not have this issue anymore.  It has the concept of different type systems, or "platform types" with Java and JavaScript platform types being different and looser than Kotlin types.  Therefore you can use a possibly null Java platform type in a place where you would not be allowed a more specific Kotlin type.  For example, the Java method returns a possibly null value, then the inferred type will be a Java platform type, and you can pass it to other things where the null checking is disabled because it is unknown for Java.  If you specifically give it a Kotlin type without using type inference, then you are coercing it into the more strict null checking, and at that line of code Kotlin will assert that the value is not null for you (same as previously using !!).

So in M9, you have two options.  Let Java types be lose and cause possible issues.  Or tell Kotlin you want to treat it specifically as nullable or not null, or use the old !! assert.